# second countable and Hausdorff doesn't imply normal

Tags: general-topology

We know that if $X$ is a second countable and regular, then it is normal. Now assume that $X$ is second countable and Hausdorff. Are there any examples to show that $X$ need not necessarily be a normal space?

Comment: I have not checked if this is in the book, but whenever I want some topology counterexample I use this book: https://www.amazon.es/Counterexamples-Topology-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/048668735X

Comment: I have checked it now, and Counterexample 75 is what you are looking for. Although it is a very rare space, that I have never heard about.

Comment: this may help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1029110/example-of-hausdorff-and-second-countable-space-that-is-not-metrizable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the simplest example is Munkres' favourite example $\Bbb R_K$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=K-topology&oldid=994452959), e.g.

It's Hausdorff, non-regular, separable and second countable.

Tip: to look for such examples in the future you can use [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=%24T_2%24%20%2B%20Second%20Countable%20%2B%20%7E%20Normal) queries. Very useful, and highly recommended; the previous example is called *Smirnov's deleted sequence topology* there.

Comment: Wow! This is a great database! Thank you so much for sharing

Answer (score 5):

Consider the subset $X=\mathbb{Q}\times \{0\}\cup \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.
For each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$, we set
$$
D_{q,r}=\{(q,0)\}\cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}\mid (x-q)^2+y^2<r\}\subset X.
$$
Equip $X$ with the weakest topology such that

- it is stronger than the topology induced from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, and
- $D_{q,r}$ is open for each $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $r\in \mathbb{Q}_{>0}$.

Then $X$ is second countable and Hausdorff, but we cannot separate $(0,0)$ and the closed subset $(\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\})\times \{0\}$ by open neighborhoods.